# How to use the 'side click' buttons of a mouse weel to scroll horizontally

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, scrolling

I have a mouse with "**side clicks**" on the scroll wheel, and I would like to use them to **scroll horizontally**.

I am using Linux Mint 20.3, and I would like to have this feature at least in graphic software, such as GIMP, Inkscape, and ImageViewer, but possibly in all the windows with an horizontal scroll bar.

**NB**: I am referring to the "click" that you perform pushing (i.e. tilting) the scroll wheel toward its side, I am not referring to the buttons on the side of the mouse. My mouse is a Logitech M590, but this feature is present on many (but not all) mice.

Comment: i have a workaround to achieve something like this by using xdotools. first try to get which event side click triggers with `xev` and simulate that to right or left click with `xdotools`. Configure this as shortcut in your DE or WM.